# How to set post_id to 0 when you upload image via Add media button. (async-upload.php)

Tags: ajax, uploads, media-library, plupload

How to set post_id to 0 when you upload image via Add media button which will make a requtest to `async-upload.php` Instead of actual post_id?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you give some context as to why to do it? Maybe there is different solution then the one you think of.

Comment: Hi Mark, I'm working on a plugin that allows registered users to write a post from front-end (and uploading images). The problem I have is that when people upload image by `Add Media` button, it will get `post_parent` ID as the parent page that contains my plugins shortcode. I'm thinking setting this to `0` when people upload images and update it to newly created post when they click submit button.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found an answer for this and checked it worked on my situation.
[How to upload image without post ID using the new media uploader?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/109417/how-to-upload-image-without-post-id-using-the-new-media-uploader)

```
// Set post_id to 0 when Add Media button clicked
jQuery('#insert-media-button').on('click', function( event ){
    event.preventDefault();
    wp.media.model.settings.post.id = 0;
});
```

This will set all the images uploaded via Add media button to 0 which will show up as `(Unattached)` in backend.